# Chokidar add event fired for all files in folder

Tags: node.js

When I use "add" event for watching a folder with Chokidar all existing files are listed as added.

Is this the correct behavior?

How can I prevent existing files from being listed and only show files that gets added?

The "change" event works as expected.

```
var watcher = chokidar.watch('/My/path', {
  ignored: /[\/\\]\./,
  persistent: true
});    

watcher
      .on('change',  function(path) { console.log("File " + path + " has been changed"); })
      .on('add',  function(path) {  console.log("File " + path + " has been added"); });
```

I'm using chokidar@1.4.3

/Christian

Answer (score 15):

Try using the `ignoreInitial` option:

```
const watcher = chokidar.watch(DIR_PATH, {
  ignoreInitial:true
});
```